# Const char * as parameters of dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I had a quick question regarding a programming assignment that i'm currently working on.
We are currently working on Dynamically Allocated Arrays.

I was able to set my "Book" object to default values / name in my constructor (using strcpy):

```
Book::Book() 
{
 strcpy(title, " ");
 strcpy(author, " ");
 price = 0.00;
}
```

However, in another function that was given in the assignement (Set function) I was unable to use the strcpy to do the same for the following:

```
void Book::Set(const char* t, const char* a, Genre g, double p)
{
    strcpy(title, *t);
    strcpy(author, *a);
    type = g;
    price = p;
}
```

My question is, how would I be able to take the information coming through the first "Const char * t" parameter, and set it to my private data char array named title[31] ?

This is my member data for my "Book" class btw:

```
private:
  char title[31];   // may assume title is 30 characters or less
  char author[21];  // may assume author name is 20 characters or 
  Genre type;       // enum Genre
  double price;
```

Let me know if I need to clarify anything,

Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

when you have questions about std functions, you should read the man. The prototype of strcpy is:

```
char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
```

So when you write: `strcpy(title, *t)`; it wouldn't compile. You should write:
`strcpy(title, t);`

One advice, when you write names of attrib in class, you should uses _ before or m_ or m like this: _title, m_title, mTitle. Just because it's dangerous to have variable with one letter name.

Another, in c++ you should use `std::string` cause it's easier to manipulate chains of caracters.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
strcpy(title, *t);
strcpy(author, *a);
```

write

```
strcpy(title, t);
strcpy(author, a);
```

This is because `strcpy` is expecting a pointer, and `*t` is not a pointer to the string.

Have a look here http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/